# Insert a listView into another listView with JqueryMobile

Tags: listview, mobile, jquery-mobile

I would like to put a listView into another listView. Is it possible? I tried this code but it doesn't work :

```
<ul data-role="listview">
    <li>
          <img src="assets/img/reception.png" alt="reception" class="ui-li-icon" />
          <a href="webmail/inbox">Boîte de r&eacute;ception</a>
    </li>
    <li class="dossiers" data-role="collapsible" style="padding:0; border-width:0;">
          <h3 style="margin:0;">Dossiers</h3>
          <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" data-theme="d">
               <li><a href="index.html">Dossier 1</a></li>
               <li><a href="index.html">Dossier 2</a></li>
               <li><a href="index.html">Dossier 3</a></li>
           </ul>
     </li>
</ul>
```

With this snippet, my button "Dossiers" disappears. Then if I comment the part`<ul>` in the `<li>`, the button re-appears.

Any idea ?

Thanks !!

Ps: Sorry for my bad English, I'm French.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like a JQM bug to me.

Try without data-role="collapsible" and if it helps - put a `div` inside the `li` and give it the role.

Also try wrapping the inner listview in a div.

[edit]

JQM alpha3 was released today. See if it fixes your problem.

Comment: I tried this and it works but not completely. In fact, the appareance of the last li into the second ul is different than the others li of this ul.
Thanks again.